# TableLayout ResourceNotFound

Tags: android, tablelayout

Android 2.3.3

I have a table, where in I have 12 columns and arbitrary number of rows. I am using the TableLayout for the first time. I have seen few examples and written a code(Not much of it). Just to populate a row with 12 columns dynamically. But I am getting an exception.. Here are the details..

Exception :::

```
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.xxx/com.xx.xxx.Portfolio}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070037 type #0x12 is not valid
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070037 type #0x12 is not valid
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.xx.xxx.Portfolio.dummy(Portfolio.java:47)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.xx.xxx.Portfolio.onCreate(Portfolio.java:28)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-11 21:57:21.569: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  ... 11 more
```

Activity :::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutPorfolio"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                    </TableLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java file :::

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Portfolio extends Activity{

    TableLayout tblPorfolio;
    TableRow trScript;
    TextView txtV;

    String[] dummy = {"1","12345","XYZABC","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000","10000"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portfolio);

        tblPorfolio = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutPorfolio);

        trScript = new TableRow(this);

        dummy();

    }

    private void dummy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i = 0;
        txtV = new TextView(this);
        while(i < dummy.length)
        {

            txtV.setText(dummy[i]);
            trScript.addView(txtV);

            i++;
        }

        tblPorfolio.addView(trScript);
        setContentView(R.id.tableLayoutPorfolio);
    }
}
```

I have to display 12 columns in one row and some N number of such rows. All these values will be retrieved from Database and populated.

Can some one let me know, what I am doing wrong (If I was doing anything right in the first place)?

Comment: Have you tried to comment this line: setContentView(R.id.tableLayoutPorfolio); ?

Comment: No.. Should i do it? I have seen it in an example and thought it should be there...

Comment: It worked.. :( Please make your comment as an answer and I will accept it..

Comment: `setContentView(R.id.tableLayoutPorfolio);` what do you expect this to do ?

Comment: @njzk2 I am using TableLayout for the first time and I have seen in an example that he set the contentview after the addview(). So thought it was needed. Thanks for the reply...

Comment: setContentView expects a layout, not an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
setContentView(R.id.tableLayoutPorfolio);
```

Because if you want to do something likt this, you need to create a layoutinflater and inflate it before you can set it as a parameter of setContentView(view).